# NullPointerException on a new activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is the class in which I implemented `onItemClickListener` and am starting the new activity. According to the logcat, the `NullPointerException` is happening while I am starting `GetAppoint`.

```
 public class Sdoctors extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public String itemselect = "";
    public doctorsDBadapter dbhelper;
    public SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sdoctors, container, false);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("By Name");
        categories.add("By Speciality");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        dbhelper = new doctorsDBadapter(getActivity());
        dbhelper.open();
        dbhelper.deletealldoctors();
        dbhelper.insertsomedoctors();
        final Cursor cursor = dbhelper.fetchalldoctors();

        String[] columns = new String[] { doctorsDBadapter.KEYNAME,
                doctorsDBadapter.KEYSPEC, doctorsDBadapter.KEYTIME };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.speac, R.id.time };

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.doctorsinfo, cursor, columns, to, 0);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.dlistView1);
        listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

                String doctor = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("_name"));

                String spec = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("_specialist"));

                String time = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("_time"));
                Log.i("DOCTOR", doctor);
                Log.i("SPECIALIST", spec);
                Log.i("TIME",time);
                Intent openApp = new Intent(view.getContext(), GetAppoint.class);
                openApp.putExtra("doct", doctor);
                openApp.putExtra("specs", spec);
                openApp.putExtra("times", time);
                startActivity(openApp);
            }
        });

        EditText myfilter = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        myfilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (itemselect == "By Speciality") {
                    return dbhelper.fetchdoctorsbyspec(constraint.toString());
                } else if (itemselect == "By Name") {
                    return dbhelper.fetchdoctorsbyname(constraint.toString());
                }
                return cursor;
            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        itemselect = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

And this is the new activity class GetAppoint.java

```
public class GetAppoint extends Activity{

ActionBar actiobar;
TextView name,spec,time;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getappoint);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    spec = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    actiobar = getActionBar();
    actiobar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actiobar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    String doc = getIntent().getExtras().getString("doct");
    String specialist = getIntent().getExtras().getString("specs");
    String doctime = getIntent().getExtras().getString("times");

    name.append(doc);
    spec.append(specialist);
    time.append(doctime);


}}
```

This is the xml file getappoint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="Specialist"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Select Date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/appointbut"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:text="Confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Logcat

```
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342): Process: com.beproject.pocketdoctor, PID: 10342
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beproject.pocketdoctor/com.beproject.pocketdoctor.GetAppoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at com.beproject.pocketdoctor.GetAppoint.onCreate(GetAppoint.java:31)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
```

Comment: Please post the Java stack trace and indicate what lines in the stack trace corresponding with what lines in your source code listings above.

Comment: This is my Logcat @CommonsWare

Comment: One of your widgets (`name`, `spec`, `time`) is not being found.

Comment: Can you please explain whats going on .., i dont understand anything.. @CommonsWare

Comment: @BalrajAllam : I have posted an answer, guess I have found out the error in your code. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering why you din't get compile time error. Your R should not contain this itself, so should have shown error.

This is your error

```
spec = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);  // text'v'iew4 'v' is in small letter
```

you are having

```
android:id="@+id/textView4"
```

Because of which your TextView is referring to null, as the element could not be found and when you are calling

.append() on that, its giving error

> 03-07 00:22:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(10342): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

Comment: +1, although android doesn't check R for compile time errors such as these, `findViewById()` will *always* return null if the resulting view cannot be found. It's good practice to check if `findViewById()` returned null before proceeding.

Comment: Whatever element you add in your XML resource file has to be made available to the java objects. So, everytime you save or build, R is generated with the new element's reference in that. In this case, R.id.textview4 should give error as in the generated R, this entry is never put.

Comment: I understand your logic, and agree it should. However the reality of the deal is that it doesn't, and you should check if `findViewById()` gives you null before doing something with the view, resulting in an NPE. This is to blame for most NPEs on android I see.

Comment: ya, thats right, null check should always b performed.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` of your `GetAppoint` Activity, you're getting the bundle from the intent,which is null because you didn't set any. Change to:

```
 String doc = getIntent().getStringExtra("doct");
 ...
```

Comment: Uhhh, isn't "getStringExtra(key)" the exact same thing as calling "getExtras().getExtra(key)", except that the convenience method has null checks within? So technically your code is identical to his (minus the NPE check, which wouldn't matter since there are clearly extras being passed). I'd second that the issue is that either his "name, spec, or time" variables are null because they weren't found in his layout.

Comment: By the time I answered he had not posted the logcat, only the code saying he was getting a NPE.  So technically, that could've been the reason. And yes, now we all know his views weren't found in the layout.